# Rewrite exponential in form $a+bi$

Tags: complex-analysis

My professor lately has become really bad at giving examples and any help with an example would be great.

if I have $e^{(2+3i)}$ how do I rewrite it as $a+bi$? is it just $2+3i$ in this case?

Comment: Do you have TI-89 ?

Comment: I do not, and won't be getting one.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not simply $2+3i$. Use Euler's formula, i.e.
$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$$

so that

$$e^{a+bi} = e^ae^{bi} = e^a(\cos b + i \sin b).$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Euler's formula, you can write
$$
e^{2+3i} = e^2 \cdot e^{3i} = e^2 (\cos(3) + i \sin(3))
$$

[image: the situation]

The length of the result number will be influenced by the real part of the argument number $2$, and the rotation by the imaginary part $3$, which is close to $\pi = 180^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks man, second time you've saved my bacon. I just needed to see an example played out.